# In Django 2.0, the Classe-based view is displaying the expected list but the function-based view does not

Tags: django, templates

I am running the Django 2.0 project and component. I wrote the class-based view and the function-based view for comparison. The url http://localhost:8000/list/ displays the expected output. But when I type in http://localhost:8000/list-fbv/ in the browser, it comes back with the error: **TemplateDoesNotExist at /list-fbv/
notes/notes_list.hmtl**.  What did I do wrong?

views.py

```
class NotesListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'notes_list'
    queryset = Notes.objects.all()

def notes_list_view(request):
    queryset = Notes.objects.all()
    context = {
        'notes_list': queryset
    }
    return render(request, "notes/notes_list.hmtl", context)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('list/', NotesListView.as_view(), name='notes_list'),
    path('list-fbv/', notes_list_view),
    path('detail/<int:id>/', NotesDetailView.as_view(), name='notes_detail'),
    path('detail-fbv/<int:pk>/', notes_detail_view),
]
```

notes_list.html

```
{% extends 'notes/_base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% for note in notes_list %}

        <p>{{note.title}}</p>
        <p>{{note.text}}</p>
        <p>{{note.timestamp}}</p>

    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You have a typo in the line ```return render(request, "notes/notes_list.hmtl", context)```, it says ```notes/notes_list.hmtl``` instead of ```notes/notes_list.html```

Comment: @Pedro Oops. One small mistake is causing a big problem. Thank you for your help.